# How can I build a Haskell program with optional dependencies?

Tags: haskell, build, dependency-management, cabal, haskell-stack

I am writing some simulation software for my own research and made a visualization tool as part of the project. This works perfectly fine on my workstation, and i can use it to for example monitor a simulation as it is running, or visualize the log data later. I have come to a point were I need to run simulations on a cluster now though, and `OpenGL` is neither available, nor needed for the actual simulations. However, since the project depends on `OpenGL`, it will not build.

Now obviously I could create a separate branch without the `OpenGL` parts, which will probably be my short term solution, but seems like a bit of a pain to maintain.

I am not sure what the best long term solution would be. Ideally I'd like to have a setup that optionally builds the visualization part if `OpenGL` is available, and skips it if not. Does `stack` (or `cabal`) support this type of thing?

Another option would be to make the visualization part a different project, but this would make monitoring the simulation as it is running significantly more difficult.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: You can work with *flags* to compile the project based on the given flags: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#flags

Comment: Do you have to build on the target machines? Can't you build and run on different machines?

Comment: I would really like to know a proper solution to this. Flags _can_ be used, but it's very fiddly.

Comment: Why would making the visualization a different project be more difficult (besides the drudgery of having to administer two projects) ? The gui-less project could provide both a standalone GUI-less executable and a library. The visualizer project could depend on the library and add GUI capabilities.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Wouldn't that still cause issues with linkning? I also use some other resources that might be system dependent, so being able to build on the system that will run it is preferable eitherway. To be honest I've never distributed binary Haskell so I am not so sure about how it would work.

Comment: @danidiaz This might be the cleanest option in the end, but I am not sure. Much of the compute code is in a language called Futhark, that can compile OpenCL, CUDA, and C, and use this for the low level stuff. I have a program that generates the Haskell FFI-code, but some details are  backend dependent. The backend I select depends on the machine, so preferably, I'd like to be able to compile everything as one package. For now I have automated the build process with a small shellscript that compiles the Futhark-code to the chosen backend, generates the FFI-code, then builds the Haskell program.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

The first and simplest would be to split up your code into two different packages.  One would be the code without the OpenGL dependency, and the other would be the visualization tool using OpenGL.  If there's no reason you can't do it this way, this is by far the best option.

If you cannot do this, then you can use Cabal flags, as someone mentioned in the comment.  An example of a cabal file with flags is:

```
name:        mylibname
description: some description

...

flag opengl
  description: build opengl support
  default:     False

library
  ...
  build-depends: base, containers, ...
  if flag(opengl)
    build-depends: OpenGL
    cpp-options: -DWITH_OPENGL
  ...
```

Now in your source files, you can do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

...

#ifdef WITH_OPENGL
    someOpenGLCode
#endif
```

By default, your builds won't include the OpenGL parts.  You can use either cabal or stack to ask to build the package with OpenGL.  In cabal, you can [either do so](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-flags) on the command line with `-f` or `--flags` option, or in the cabal.project file with the `flags:` field.  Someone else already linked to what looks like some equivalent stack documentation (though I don't know stack well enough to comment on its correctness)